Database or arrays
Generally for an RPG, would you say a DB like SQL server and MYSQL is over kill? RDB seems really convenient to pull and call from an inventory item for example, yet I see arguments that it is too slow and convoluted and that arrays are generally preferred in this use case, with JSON being the usual choice. Can I get more elaboration on this?

I'd recommend not developing by hearsay. Is your database approach fast enough for your use case when you profile it? If so, that's what matters, not whether some strangers on the Internet say it could be faster. If not, share your profiling results and we can help you optimize your solution for the use cases that are currently problematic in your game.

Also even with a database, you would not perform live queries against the db all the time. Once per game start and each time you update your inventor, but those should be write requests against it.
